# CSS selector by title value

Tags: html, css

I have multiple html pages with same structure and i want to change style of specific class (for example .button) only in one of those html pages (same structure pages)
The only unique thing about those html pages is title names unique name
My question is it possible to select a specific class using css, where title name is "unique name"?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>unique name</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="button"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: From css it's not possible but you could achieve this with javascript

Comment: (But even if the answer to the duplicate wasn't "No", that would still not help you here - because even if you _were_ able to select the `title` element based on its content, you couldn't use that to influence how that button looks. That would only be possible if the button was a following _sibling_ of `title`, or contained in one.)